# How do I set up PhpStorm to show code coverage for Jest AND PhpUnit?

Tags: laravel, jestjs, phpunit, phpstorm, code-coverage

Web Framework: Laravel 6

IDE: PhpStorm

Other:

- Inertia.js
- Vue.js

Testing:

- Backend: PhpUnit
- Frontend: Jest

---

On my Laravel 6 project, I'm using Inertia to connect Laravel to Vue. In my root folder, I have my phpunit.xml and jest.config.ts. My IDE is PhpStorm.

For backend testing, I have a "tests" folder that comes with every Laravel 6 folder. This uses PhpUnit.

For frontend testing, I have a "__tests__" folders in root/resources/js. This uses Jest.

When I run (with coverage) a configuration for either Jest or PhpUnit, it will ask me if I want to replace active suites. No, I don't want to replace them. I want to see the percentages of all my files' coverage, both frontend and backend.

[image: My file directory after running PhpUnit]

Ideally, I should also see percents of coverage next to the "resources" folder. However, when I run Jest with coverage, I have no choice but to replace the percentages next to "app" and "base".

[image: My file directory after running Jest]

This is what the dialog looks like.

[image: code coverage dialog]

As it stands, I can only look at one at a time, and if I want to look at the other suite, I must run with coverage again.

Is there any way I can configure it where I can see it all at once?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can generate and then display both coverage reports within the IDE. What I mean is: if you generate coverage report somewhere outside of the IDE (e.g. using External Tools functionality or whatnot) then you should be able to *manually append* it there. It can be added by using `Run | Show Coverage Data` where you can add such an extra coverage reports. NOTE: the IDE will not reload modified report (with new data): you will need to remove and re-add it again... At very least that was the case before (7 or so years ago when I had to use it this way)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. I've pushed it to our issue tracker, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67832/Code-coverage-Support-Add-to-active-suites-for-different-test-frameworks-PHPUnit-Jest